# Does a Context Condition Path need to exist?

Tags: 7

I have a context that has a condition Path of FooBar/*
I added a block (Reaction) view for that context.
When I go to /FooBar/Mens_Bible_Studies, the view shows, but I also get "Page not found"?

```
Page not found

    Mens Bible Studies

    Overview of Mens Bible Studies. Delete if you don't want an overview
        Curabitur tortor - Meets every Wednesday, 6:30 am.

The requested page "/FooBar/Mens_Bible_Studies" could not be found.
```

What am I missing?

Rich

Update based upon the first two responses.

Thanks Boriana and rooby for answering! Here is a little more about what I am doing. At this point I am really not sure why I didn't use a page view. I am leaning to using contexts instead of panels. I want a responsive site and the theme handles that for me so I don't want to force a layout with panels. I want to select my block view based upon the "FooBar" root path.
I have a fairly large number of content types tagged with different taxonomy terms. I have a compound view that does all the work. It just looks at the last leaf of the URL (/FooBar/bla1/bla2/blanN... there is a variable depth) and uses that as the taxonomy term and builds a recursive output that descends the taxonomy tree in a way that I can CSS style each level differently. Content tagged as sub-category heading displays differently than content tagged with terminal terms (the lowest level in the branch of the taxonomy hierarchy they are in). I have heading content and then child content under that in the term hierarchy.
I thought I could just have the reaction point to the view and have it output. I will try both approaches you both suggested to see what works best. I believe I have to go with rooby's suggestion since I don't think I can have menu entries point to non-existent content. After I posted, I was thinking of just creating a panel page with empty variants that reacted to all the URLs I needed to create. Each of these would point to the same block view.

So Ideally, the new module I would need create (I never created a module before) would take a list of my hierarchical URLs, create phantom pages for them and create menu entries for them. My context would provide the content.

Or, perhaps I should just commandeer the taxonomy term views with what I want since the URLs that I want match the taxonomy term hierarchy.

Comment: So, you want the view without a page actually existing there in the first place?  Then why not make the view into a page view versus making it into a block that shows up *on* a page.  If you don't already have a page, just make a page view with that URL.  Or am I misunderstanding the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the context module does not create pages, it allows you to position blocks on existing pages.

If you want a page that is not a node or a view you can use the [empty page](http://drupal.org/project/empty_page) module or the [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.

If you want a bunch of pages that are dynamic like FooBar/* where there are lots of sub pages, you could also create a custom module to create the pages, by using [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and returning an empty string for you page content.